# Pass (argc, argv) variables to a function as (argv, argc) inside main in C++

Tags: c++

I am using a function from a library that calls for the (argc,argv) command line functions from the main program to be passed directly to it; however, I only want to pass some arguments to it with the rest being evaluated in the main code not function. Below is a sample of the main code with evaluating arguments.

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
     // Evaluate arguments
if ( argc > 9 ) {
    PrintUsage();
    return 1;
}
G4String input;
G4String macro;
G4String physicslist;
for ( G4int i=1; i<argc; i=i+2 ) {
    if      ( G4String(argv[i]) == "-i" ) macro = argv[i+1];
    else if ( G4String(argv[i]) == "-l" ) physicslist = argv[i+1];
    else if ( G4String(argv[i]) == "-g" ) input = argv[i+1];
    else if //pass the rest of the arguments to function below
  G4MPImanager* g4MPI = new G4MPImanager(argc,argv);
```

Any other arguments not evaluated above I want to pass to the function from an outside library, which requires being called as shown.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a well thought through section of code, but you haven't actually asked a question. Are you looking for a way to detect all of the arguments that aren't "-i", "-l" and "-g", or their following arguments?

Comment: You should use standard program argument parsing techniques, like `getopt` or `argp` [from GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments). Accepting the usual `--help` and `--version` arguments per GNU conventions is very useful. Then you can build your library `argc` +  `argv` arguments (beware that `argv[argc]` should be `NULL`)

Answer (score 2):

`argv` is simply an array of char pointers terminated by a final `NULL` pointer. You can create your own using `my_argv = new char *[number_of_items + 1]`, where `number_of_items` is the number of arguments you want to cherry-pick from "real" `argv` (or your own strings). Such array can be passed to `G4MPIManager` constructor instead of the actual `argv` received in `main()`.

Additional notes:

- Don't forget to terminate `argv` with a NULL pointer.
- The first member of `argv`, `argv[0]`, will be expected to hold the "program name" and as such will be either ignored or only used to prefix diagnostic messages. Simply reuse the `argv[0]` you get from `main()`.
- `argc` should be such that `argv[argc] == NULL`, i.e. the same as the `number_of_items` above. Given that the `argv` array must contain program name as first member, `argc` will never be 0.

Comment: `argc` may be zero, although POSIX requires the first argument to indicate how the program was invoked. I think you mean `number_of_items` can never be zero.

Comment: Alternatively, if your program will be 'consuming' `argv` items that are passed to `main()` it's perfectly acceptable to remove those items by moving the remaining items in `argv` down, for example.  Just remember to account for the removal in `argc` (of course) and to set `argv[argc]` to `NULL` as mentioned several times here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter The wording of my answer was imprecise. While it is true that `argc` may not be zero when creating and argv/argc pair mimicking those passed to `main()`, that does not follow from the `argv[argc] == NULL` invariant, as implied by "in other words". I've now rephrased the answer to be clearer about that.

Answer (score 2):

Create a vector of strings.
Erase the arguments you don't want from the vector.
You can then create a `char*[]` from the vector very easily (at the size is trivial).

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
      std::vector<char*>  args(argv, argv+argc+1);  // +1 to catch the last NULL at argv[argc]

      for(auto loop = args.begin(); loop != args.end();)
      {
          if      (/*Your Test 1 */) { /*STUFF 1*/ loop = args.erase(loop);}
          else if (/*Your Test 2 */) { /*STUFF 2*/ loop = args.erase(loop);}
          else                       { ++loop; /* If you did not remove it increment loop*/ }
      }
      // args.size() -1 becuase we have the extra NULL as the last argument.
      //             and argv[arc] should be null
      // &args[0]    is the address of the first member.
      //             vector keeps its data in contiguous memory so will look like an array
      G4MPImanager* g4MPI = new G4MPImanager(args.size() - 1, &args[0]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to construct new pair of argc and argv for whatever your `i` is and then pass it to your function.

```
int newArgc = argc - i;
char** newArgv = &argv[i];
G4MPImanager* g4MPI = new G4MPImanager(newArgc, newArgv);
```